# Java FileOutputStream try block is not being run. It immediately skips to the catch block

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, serializable

Here are my fields:

```
final class Player implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2676858593456923114L;
    private final transient String filename = "BSR.data";
    private int hp;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private ArrayList<ArrayList> inventory = new ArrayList<>(); //This will be used to store the other 
                                                                //inventories.
    private ArrayList<String> myLevelUps = new ArrayList<>(); //This will be used to store the collection 
                                                              //of level up items the player gets.
    private ArrayList<Crystal> myCrystals = new ArrayList<>(); //This will be used to store the 
                                                               //collection of crystals that the player 
                                                              //gets.
    private ArrayList<Weapon> myWeapons = new ArrayList<>(); //This will be used to store the collection 
                                                             //of weapons that the player gets.
    private int myLevel = 0;//a modifier.
    private int myGold;
```

Here is the method that isn't doing what it is supposed to do:

```
void save(Player player) {
        
        try
        {
        // Create a file to write game system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (filename);

        // Code to write instance of Player will go here
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream (out);

        // Write Player system to object store
        objectOut.writeObject (player);
        
        // Close object output stream
        objectOut.close();
        
        System.out.println("Your game has been saved to" + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Unable to create game data");
        }
        
    }
```

What should happen is a file is created using the filename in the fields. However, as the question states, the whole of the try block is simply skipped immediately. and the catch block is run. I checked all the fields, and they are all serializable, so that is not the problem. Where did I go wrong? I used a tutorial to get the code down.

Comment: We need to see the exception.  In your catch block, e.printStackTrace() so you can see what happened

Comment: Change your code in the `catch` to `e.printStackTrace()` and see where the error is occurring.

Comment: If method `save` is in class `Player`, maybe you should make it a static method?

Comment: You should indeed print the exception stack trace to know more. But if you're getting the exception on the first line of your try (where you initialize the FileOutputStream), there is a very high chance that the file "BSR.data" is not located where the Java process runs.

Comment: You should learn about try-with-resources.

Comment: Thank you guys soooo much! It was simply the fact that another class I was placing into a list was NOT serializable. This was my first foray into serializing and didn't know that the stuff IN the lists ALSO needed to be serializable. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like David Zimmerman says, put e.printStackTrace() in catch block to see the exception. Also I suspect that you are executing wrong the method. With your implementation you have to do something like this:

```
Player p = new Player(...);
p.save(p);
```

I maked a test with that code and it work fine. But this is ugly because you have to pass an external reference to the object itself. I recommend you to remove "Player player" parameter from "save" function and write the object in this way:

```
objectOut.writeObject(this);
```

Then you can do somethig like this:

```
Player p = new Player();
p.save();
```

I tested in this way and works fine too.

You can make it even better if you put the resources auto closeables inside try-with-resources (as Raedwald says), in that way you won't have to worry about closing every resource.

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);) {
```

The you can remove following line:

```
objectOut.close();
```